Не работает position: sticky при включенном overflow-x: hidden, но необходимо сохранить оба свойства
В моём проекте применены такие проблемные стили:
html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header { 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0px;
}

Если убрать overflow-x: hidden, позиционирование header работает замечательно, но мне важно оставить оба стиля. Есть ли варианты решения этой проблемы?

нет. position:sticky не будет работать если в любом из предков overflow: hidden

добавь пример своей разметки в вопрос. Возможно тебе поможет просто убрать html из твоего стиля

position:sticky не работает, если у любого из контейнеров установлено свойство overflow.
Однако, элементы html и body несколько отличаются. Если overflow-x: hidden будет установлено только у одного из них - sticky продолжит работать, при условии, что больше ни у одного из предков не будет выставлен overflow.


document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]').forEach(c => {
  c.addEventListener('change', e => {
    document.querySelector(c.dataset.selector).style.overflowX = !c.checked ? '' : 'hidden';
  })
})
header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: red;
}
<div>
  <header>Header
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-selector="body"> hidden on body</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-selector="html"> hidden on html</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-selector="div"> hidden on div container</label>
  </header>

  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>




Нашёл костыль. Задал max-width у контейнера с переполнением. Сталкивался с проблемой того, что единицы viewport не учитывают ширину скроллбара, поэтому пришлось дополнительно использовать JS.
Решение:
JS
  const scrollbarWidth =
    window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  if (scrollbarWidth > 0) {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
      "--scrollbarWidth",
      scrollbarWidth + "px"
    );

CSS
:root {
  --adjusted-vw: calc(100vw - var(--scrollbarWidth));
}

.overflowed-container {
  max-width: var(--adjusted-vw);
}


Вся сложность проблемы в том, что необходимо было ограничить контейнер с Lottie-анимацией, который рендерит модуль, задавая собственные стили. Переписывать модуль под себя не очень хотелось, обошёл через это.
